# FullCalendar v4 - How to dynamically add a non-standard field in the calendar?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-modal, dom-events, fullcalendar-4

I added a non-standard field in the modal / form (Bootstrap) to add it to the calendar event. I take the content of the textarea and save it in a variable (description) but I can't print it in the calendar. I was researching and testing with `eventRender` but it didn't work. What do you suggest?

```
      // FULLCALENDAR
      document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
        // Submit formulario
        let enviar = document.querySelector("#guardar"); 
        let calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');

        let calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
          locale: "es",
          plugins: ["interaction", "dayGrid", "timeGrid"],
          selectable: true,
          defaultView: "timeGridWeek",
          header: {
            left: "prev,next today",
            center: "title",
            right: "timeGridDay,timeGridWeek,dayGridMonth",
          },

          // Selecciona con click en una fecha/hora determinada
          dateClick: function (info) {
            let infoDate = info.dateStr.substring(0,10)
            let infoTime = info.dateStr.substring(11,19)

            // Toma el valor donde clikea y lo agrega al value de HTML
            document.querySelector("#fecha").setAttribute("value", infoDate)
            document.querySelector("#hora").setAttribute("value", infoTime)

            // Acciona el modal
            $("#modalEventos").modal();
          },
        });

        calendar.render();

        // EVENT LISTENER
        enviar.addEventListener("submit", enviarEvento)

        // FUNCTIONS
        // Toma los datos del evento en el modal 
        function enviarEvento() {
          let titulo = document.querySelector("#titulo").value;
          let descripcion = document.querySelector("#descripcion").value;
          let fecha = document.querySelector("#fecha").value;
          let hora = document.querySelector("#hora").value;
          let color = document.querySelector("#color").value;

          // Imprime los datos en el calendario
          calendar.addEvent({    
            title: titulo, 
            description: descripcion,
            start: fecha + "T" + hora,
            color: color
          });

          //Cierra el modal
          $('#modalEventos').modal('toggle'); 
        }
      });
```

Answer (score 3):

**Full calendar < 4.x**

According to [docs](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v1/addEvent), **addEvent** was removed in `v1.3`.

The alternative syntax is:

```
calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', {    
  // event props here...
}, true);
```

If you need more help, please create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to allow testing potential solutions.

Here's a [codepen](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/pogRGNB) where you can see the above syntax working (line `16` in JS).
To test: click any day, add details, "Save".

---

**Full calendar 4.x and above:**

According to [documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-parsing), every non-standard property passed to the `event` object and any property passed to `event.extendedProps` will all be merged inside the same object, called `extendedProps` which means both `department` and `foo` in this example will be found in `event.extendedProps` after parsing:

```
calendar.addEvent({
  title: 'BCH237',
  start: '2019-08-12T10:30:00',
  end: '2019-08-12T11:30:00',
  department: 'BioChemistry',
  extendedProps: {
    foo: 'bar'
  },
  description: 'Lecture'
})
... 
eventRender(info) {
  console.log(info.event.extendedProps.department) // 'BioChemistry'
  console.log(info.event.extendedProps.foo) // 'bar'
  console.log(info.event.description) // 'Lecture'
}
```

See it [working here](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/JjGWWwP?editors=0010).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the reply @tao. renderEvent is only available until version 3 and I'm using v 4. So I use [calendar.addEvent](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/Calendar-addEvent) which is available in version 4 and 5 (beta). (I think it is not the same as addEvent, to which you refer)
I am a newbie to javascrip so I keep trying a solution and watch for suggestions!
Seeks to fix it in JavaScript, avoiding jQuery.

FullCalendar gives me this [reference](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/event-object) but when I try to do it dynamically I can't

```
                    var calendar = new Calendar(calendarEl, {
          events: [
            {
              title: 'BCH237',
              start: '2019-08-12T10:30:00',
              end: '2019-08-12T11:30:00',
              extendedProps: {
                department: 'BioChemistry'
              },
              description: 'Lecture'
            }
            // more events ...
          ],
          eventRender: function (info) {
            console.log(info.event.extendedProps);
            // {description: "Lecture", department: "BioChemistry"}
          }

        });
```

Comment: Don't use an answer to reply to mine. Only use answers to answer the question. It looks like you didn't provide all the required info in your question. Which means you should delete this answer and update your question with sufficient info about your problem. Ideally, you should provide a [mcve] so that anyone could test their answers against it.

Comment: Updated the answer to answer your real question. IMHO, you should update the question to include full details of what you're asking. Please read [ask].

Answer (score 0):

For a version 5 try this.

```
           calendar.addEvent({
                title: $('#txtTituloEvento').val(),
                start: $('#txtInicio').val(),
                end: $('#txtFin').val(),
                extendedProps: {
                    descripcion: $('#txtDescripcion').val()
                },
                allDay: false,
            })
```